# Checking vanishing at cusps from the $q$-expansion

Tags: modular-forms

I am trying to understand cusp forms, for a congruence subgroup. As an example, take $\Gamma_0(p)$, for $p$ a prime. As I understand there are two cusps, $0$ and $i\infty$, which are the $\Gamma_0(p)$ orbits of $i(\mathbb Q \cup \infty)$.

Checking a form $f$ for $\Gamma_0(p)$ vanishes at $\tau = i\infty$ is simple as you just check it vanishes for $q=0$. So let's assume that's true so that $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n q^n$.

To check $\tau = 0$, i.e. $q = 1$ means proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 0$, which is often not trivial. So how does one usually approach showing this? I had the idea you could choose a different point in the same class, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ takes you to $\tau = p$ but you still have to show the sum of the coefficients vanishes. Is there a trick to checking vanishing at cusps (and more generally checking holomorphicity at cusps when you have the $q$-expansion)? Also I noticed that $0$ is not in the upper half plane, so it seems there is an issue there, when it is touted as a cusp but I am assuming there is a point I am missing.

Comment: Use the modularity of $\,f\,$ to connect its values at $\,i\infty\,$ and at a cusp.

Comment: @Somos What if you have a cusp that can't be reached by a transformation from $i\infty$? That is, if it does not lie in that equivalence class.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Somos Can we discuss an example? I made a room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118770/modular-forms-discussion

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount of information you have on $f$.

For $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n e^{2i\pi nz} \in M_k(\Gamma_0(p))$ with **integer** coefficients bounded like $|a_n|\le C n^m$,

[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricke_involution) $$z^{-k} f(-1/(pz))=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n e^{2i\pi nz} \in S_k(\Gamma_0(p)),\qquad  c_0=\int_i^{i+1}z^{-k} f(-1/(pz)) dz\in \Bbb{Z}$$
Whence $c_0=0$ iff for some $N$ $$|\int_i^{i+1}z^{-k} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n e^{2i\pi(-1/(pz)) }dz|<1-\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |\int_i^{i+1}z^{-k} e^{2i\pi(-1/(pz)) }dz|$$
In other words knowing the bound $Cn^m$ allows to check if it is a cusp form solely from the first few coefficients.

Certainly the bound $C n^m$ itself can be found from the first few coefficients, at this point I would look into https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10908 and parigp and sage implementations of modular forms.

Comment: How do you propose to check whether an infinite sequence is bounded by checking the first few coefficients?

Comment: It is not quite an arbitrary infinite sequence but a linear combination of the finitely many eigenforms $\in M_k(\Gamma_0(p))$, given $p,k$ there is $B(p,k)$ (the Sturm bound but choosing it larger may simplify the expressions?) such that we can deduce an upper bound for $\sup_n |f(n)/n^{k+1}|$ from $\sup_{n\le B(p,k)} |f(n)|$, I guess the obtained map will be elementary and that proving it works will be hard.

Comment: (both $\sup_n |f(n)/n^{k+1}|$ and $\sup_{n\le B(p,k)} |f(n)|$ are norms on the $\Bbb{C}$-vector space $ M_k(\Gamma_0(p))$)

Comment: For this to work, you would need to know a basis for $M_k$ and a characterisation of which linear combinations of those basis vectors lay in $S_k$; so you'd already have solved the problem.